# How to move tabs in Visual Studio Code with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I found the documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8234#issuecomment-234573410) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) (under `moveActiveEditor`) for moving tabs, but I have trouble creating a key binding for it.

I created the following (for a Mac, so it uses `cmd`):

```
[
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+right",
    "command": "moveActiveEditor",
    "args": {
      "to": "position",
      "value": i + 1
    }
  }
]
```

But when I hit that key command, the tab moves to the first tab position instead of moving one tab position to the right. So clearly, the value of `i` is `0`, meaning it isn't returning the correct value of the current tab.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to replace `position` with `right` and remove the value attribute:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+right",
    "command": "moveActiveEditor",
    "args": {
      "to": "right"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can find this with `cmd+p`: `> preferences: open keyboard shortcuts (json)`